# How can I tell if an event has had "stopImmediatePropagation()" called on it?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm reusing the native Event class for my own Object Model.

I've found and made use of the `Event.stopBubbling` property, which does get set to true after `Event.stopPropagation()` is called.  But I can't seem to find any special properties which get modified by `Event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

***How can I tell if an event has had `stopImmediatePropagation()` called on it?***

Are there any properties it modifies, or perhaps some hook I can listen to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With jQuery:**

If you using `stopImmediatePropagation` of jQuery then i saw the following jQuery code on its GitHub repository.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/899c56f6ada26821e8af12d9f35fa039100e838e/src/event.js#L594

following is the definition of `stopImmediatePropagation` there:

```
stopImmediatePropagation: function() {
    var e = this.originalEvent;

    this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnTrue;

    if ( e && !this.isSimulated ) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

    this.stopPropagation();
}
```

so it looks like `Event.isImmediatePropagationStopped` is the way to find out what you need.

**Without jQuery:**

if you are trying to achieve the same without jQuery then i think there is no native way to find out if `stopImmediatePropagation` is actually called. but the following code can be used to override the original `stopImmediatePropagation` and get it working like the above.

```
stopImmediatePropagationOriginal = Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation;
Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation = function(event){
    stopImmediatePropagationOriginal.bind(this).call(event);
    this.isImmediatePropagationStopped=true;
};
```

so with the above code you can use `Event.isImmediatePropagationStopped` to find out what you need.